# Saving/Exporting Unit Test Results in VS 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

How can I export unit tests results in VS 2012?  I know there's never been a direct way to do it (even though there should be), but at least in 2012 I was able to save the results from the test result window, and use trx2html to convert them into something readable.  In 2012, I don't see any way to do this from the test explorer.  Unit tests results are part of our project documentation, so my ability to do this is important.

Any tips would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently no way to export your results out from the IDE while using the new execution engine in VS2012. However you can achieve this via the commandline vstest.console.exe using the /logger:trx option.

Comment: Thanks Allen.  It's disappointing that this feature was removed from the IDE, but at least it's there.

Comment: You should upvote the feature request on uservoice as many of the VS teams track that for bumping up priorities. While not exactly an export/save option - as a workaround you can Ctrl-C in the test explorer and paste the entire results into your editor and save it

Comment: I was only able to Ctrl-C one result at a time, not all of them?

Comment: Unfortunately Yes - useful for getting the failing test method stack trace and output

Answer (score 1):

1. Build the solution
2. Run the Command prompt in Administrator mode.
3. Go the following path
   CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
4. Type the follwoing command 
   mstest /testcontainer:[Unit test project dll folder path] /resultsfile:[Output Folder Path]\result.trx
5. Go to the Output path and check the trx file created in that path. Open this path from visual studio.
   [image]

Comment: We faced some issue while executing the test cases for the entire assembly from command line. These passed from IDE. There was some threading issue.

Comment: did you tried to test it from visual studio Test explorer?