# Save Results in Visual Studio 2012 Test Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nunit, ui-automation

I have been working on `UI Automation` to perform unit testing using `NUnit` in Visual Studio 2012. The NUnit is integrated in my `VS2012`. 
I need to store the results of the test such as pass/fail status, the error message and the other available details in the test explorer somewhere in a human readable form. 
I know that VS2010 we used to get the `.trx` file which could be used further. How do I get the result in VS2012? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I can at least assure you that it's possible with TFS, as we did this in our company. But I don't remember every detail. The basic steps are:

- Create a build definition to run NUnit tests (use the conrole runner for this)
- Transform the result XML (TestResult.xml) to VS format (.trx) using a tool. There are several around, try to g00g1e it.
- Publish the transformed results to TFS (done in the build script).

It seems that it is not possible to somehow log all test results, when run directly in VS. In this case the only chance you have, is to run the tests externally using the NUnit runners (GUI or Console) and store the `TestResults.xml` output file.

Comment: I know that using console runner we can do this stuff. Is there any way using VS2012 directly? or using NUnit console is the only option I have?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. There is the *VSTestAdapter* for NUNit, see http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.3

Comment: I already have NUnit integrated into VS2012 using the VSTestAdapter. I am able to run the test perfectly without any problem. The result of the tests in VS2012 is displayed under the Test Explorer. Now, what I want to do is to store the results of the executed test somewhere. I dont want to run it using NUnit console or the gui but I want to run the test in VS2012 itself, which is not the problem. The problem is to how to store the results of test run in VS2012?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528619/saving-exporting-unit-test-results-in-vs-2012/29432673#29432673